# После динамичного добавления блока не получается повесить на него событие

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-events

У меня есть два input где я ввожу url и alt картинки. Потом через JS создаю блок div, записываю в тег img значения двух input и вывожу на страницу. Потом хочу повесить событие на динамически созданный div, но у меня выходит ошибка, что событие null (логично, ведь его не существует). Я могу конечно заранее создать пустой блок в html и туда динамически добавлять img, но стало интересно как-то можно обойти этот момент?

```html
<body>
    <form action="" class="form-addImage" name="addImage">
        <input class="form-input form-input-mainUrl" name="mainUrl" type="text" placeholder="url картинки"/>
        <input class="form-input form-input-altText" name="altText" type="text" placeholder="альтернативное описание картинки"/>
        <button class="form-button form-add-button" name="formAddBtn" type="button">Add image</button>
        <button class="form-button form-delete-button" name="formDeleteBtn" type="button">Delete image</button>
    </form>
    
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
let form = document.forms.addImage
let mainUrl = form.mainUrl
let altText = form.altText

let addButton = form.formAddBtn
addButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (mainUrl.value != '') {
        const div = document.createElement('div')
        div.classList.add('image-wrapper')

        const img = document.createElement('img')
        img.src = mainUrl.value
        img.alt = altText.value
        div.append(img)

        //div.innerHTML = `<img src="${mainUrl.value}" alt="${altText.value}">`

        document.body.append(div)
        mainUrl.value = ''
        altText.value = ''
    }
})

let deleteButton = form.formDeleteBtn
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const imageWrapper = document.querySelector('.image-wrapper')
    if (imageWrapper != null) {
        imageWrapper.remove()
    }
})

let imageWrapper = document.querySelector('.image-wrapper')
imageWrapper.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (altText.value === '') {
        imageWrapper.style.border = '1px solid red'
    }
})
```

Comment: Где в вашем коде попытки повесить событие на создаваемый DIV? Что это за событие такое(клик?) и привидите полный текст ошики, которая у вас появляется

Comment: Вот ошибка: _index.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at index.js:42:14_
Если я создам div заранее в html все работает. Не работает когда я создаю div через js. 
PS Я исправил сообщение, потому что там не правильно указал  названия события.

Comment: Реализуйте через делегирование событий: https://sky.pro/media/privyazka-sobytij-k-dinamicheski-sozdannym-elementam-v-javascript/

Comment: @humster_spb, я делал это. Просто хотел попробовать без делегирования.

Comment: А почему надо без делегирования?

Comment: Задание такое‍♀️ В первый раз без делегирования, второй с делегированием

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вешайте событие сразу после создания div

```js
let addButton = form.formAddBtn
addButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (mainUrl.value != '') {
        const div = document.createElement('div')
        div.classList.add('image-wrapper')

        const img = document.createElement('img')
        img.src = mainUrl.value
        img.alt = altText.value
        div.append(img)

        //div.innerHTML = `<img src="${mainUrl.value}" alt="${altText.value}">`

        document.body.append(div)
        mainUrl.value = ''
        altText.value = ''

        let imageWrapper = div
        imageWrapper.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if (altText.value === '') {
                imageWrapper.style.border = '1px solid red'
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: спасибо большое, работает! Сам бы не додумался)

Comment: У меня один момент появился. Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на картинку у меня изображение обрамлялось красной рамкой, если значение атрибута alt пустое и в консоль писалось значение атрибута alt, если оно не пустое. Но я не понимаю почему, у меня выполняется всегда одно условие:
https://pastebin.com/nz0Xmene

Comment: Это уже вопрос отладки. Ставьте прерывание, смотрите, какое значение приходит. https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome

Comment: Я смотрел через отладчик но ничего не находил. Ваше сообщение натолкнуло меня посмотреть внимательнее и подумать получше. В итоге выяснил, что я использовал querySelector и он мне возвращал первый попавшийся элемент. А надо было использовать querySelectorAll, через foreach пройтись по все блокам и повесить на них обработчик события.  Спасибо вам)